# Does windows 8.1 default theme drains more power?

Tags: themes, battery-life

The default theme of windows 8.1, not the high contrast theme, drains lot of power from the laptop battery? (when the laptop is not connected to the power supply).

If yes, then which theme to use that do not drain lot of power from the battery compared to the default theme?

Comment: This a question or a statement?  I very much doubt the default theme uses more power then another other theme.

Comment: ok. Its a question. Is there any way to bring windows classic theme back on windows 8.1?

Comment: What theme are you talking about exactly?  Most of the Winows 7 themes were retired because `Aero` is disabled in Windows 8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On older versions of Windows, back when "Classic" was still an option, there was no discernable difference, that I could tell, in battery life between when my netbook was in Classic mode and when I finally switched to XP's normal theme.  The Windows theme is not a significant part of your battery drain.  Screen brightness matters a lot more.  When you're running in power-saver modes, some screen animations may not be quite as zippy, but they won't make your battery life noticeably shorter.